# Collecting comma "," separated data from given tables

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to solve a sql query where there are three table TABLE 1, TABLE 2 AND TABLE3 as in given image below

[image]

as in Table1 there are two columns user_id and user_name . in table 2 there are three columns id1(auto generated) , user_id (same as table1's user_id) and role_id. In table 3 again there are three columns id2(auto generated), role_id(same as table2's role_id) and role_name. Finally i am expecting a resulted table as given resultant table where there is a choosen rows and separated by comma "," .Please give idea or query to solve this.

Comment: Choose your database:  MySQL or SQL Server.  And tag appropriately.

Comment: hi many thanks for the reply. i wants to do for sql-server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql-server]+group_concat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea here is `For XML path` which will `concat` your `rows` into CSV

```
SELECT ', ' + d.roleid as Concat_roleid
FROM   table3 d
FOR XML PATH('')

SELECT a.userid,
       Stuff((SELECT ', ' + d.roleid
              FROM   table3 d
              WHERE  d.id2 = c.id2
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') Roleid,
       Stuff((SELECT ', ' + e.Rolename
              FROM   table3 e
              WHERE  e.id2 = c.id2
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') Rolename
FROM   table1 a
       JOIN table2 B
         ON a.userid = b.userid
       JOIN table3 C
         ON c.roleid = b.roleid
GROUP  BY a.userid
```

Comment: i did not understand by stuff, what does stuff by means?

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay - Here stuff is used to remove the **leading comma**. Check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms188043.aspx. You can use any other String function like `Right` , `Substring` to remove that leading comma